# CPU i5 750 stuck at its idle multiplier. Even when used at max

Tags: cpu, intel-core-i5

My [i5 750](http://ark.intel.com/products/42915) seems to be stuck on the idle multiplier (9x) instead of the base speed of 2.66 GHz, even while loading using Prime 95

Configuration:

- [i5 750](http://ark.intel.com/products/42915)
- [DP55WB](http://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/motherboards/desktop-motherboards/desktop-board-dp55wb.html) desktop motherboard.
- 2GB DDR3 RAM
- PSU: Corsair Vx450W
- GPU: MSI ATI 5770 HAWK

[image]

Any idea whats going on?

In addition to the troubleshooting in the comments, I tried going to power options and setting the minimum processor state to 100%. No effect at all

Comment: Need information on the BIOS settings.    Are you unable to change the multiplier in BIOS?  I would try restoring the default settings.

Comment: @Ramhound I tried Reset defaults but did not try setting an explicit multiplier given the huge warning about breaking something before I could get to the config screen. Is it relatively safe to use the settings to force a multiplier supported on stock since the processor does not seem to be using it automatically ?

Comment: I just fired up CPU-Z on my own desktop and I can at least confirm that the multiplier it shows should change when the CPU is non-idle. I just watched my go from the normal x12 (idle) to [x21](http://i.stack.imgur.com/Mi3rD.png) (during prime95 stressing).

Comment: @Hennes yup, thats how its supposed to happen and used to happen (and similarly, the temps dont increase either, usually they used to flat out at 80C on P95, now they flat out at 55-60C)

Comment: @Akash - I would assume its safe to change the multipler to the stock multipler. I mean if this is brand new hardware there is a small possability your dealing with fake or defective hardware. A 20x multiplier would give you 2,666.8 which is the base frequency ( or close enough it won't matter ). The cause of your multiplier being locked at 9 is really strange. If this is new I would RMA both the motherboard and CPU.  Were you trying to overclock your system by change? Its almost like you locked a mode design to hand tune your overclock.

Comment: @Ramhound Nope :(  Its a 3 year old system . No overclocking or anything. Was facing a no POST scenario and worked fine after removing a RAM stick last month. Had attributed the sluggish performance to running it on 2GB RAM. Noticed the processor clock speed being so low today

Comment: @Akash - Alright.  Your inability to POST in the past is important information.  This points to a possible BIOS configuration corruption.  I would attempt to apply the current BIOS update and see if it will allow you to reapply it.

Comment: @Ramhound: Dropping to a low multiplier at idle is operating as designed. I see the same thing when I do mild stuff such as browsing Stack exchange.  (X12 in the case of my i920). The multiplier only goes up to max (even even shortly beyond that when turbo-boost is enabled) when the CPU is heavily used. In the case of sustained max usage (e.g. prime95) it simply should set all cores to max normal multiplier.

Comment: @Ramhound So, the BIOS doesnt have any option to explicitly set a multiplier. The only options for the CPU I had were to set the CPU Idle state (which I set to High Performance instead of Low Power) and Maximum Non Turbo Ratio (Which is set to the default of 20). I did not touch the voltage or Memory overclocking settings, or the Host Clock frequency settings which are all on defaults. The inability to POST was due to a bad RAM slot (the beep codes indicated bad RAM).

Comment: Hesitant to apply a BIOS update since I believe it can lead to an unbootable system instead of a slow running one, and my machine is out of warranty so it would be a MAJOR issue

Comment: @Akash it can only lead to a unbootable if something does wrong cut currently something is wrong.  The bios update might be the only way to fix it